# How to get Google Finance Intraday data into Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I want to import data from following link into Google Spreadsheet

https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=BANKBARODA&x=NSE&i=900&p=1d&f=v&df=cpct&auto=1&ts=1266701290218

Which formula is appropriate to import?

Comment: Can you link to any documentation for those query parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=GOOGLEFINANCE()` is appropriate. But you can also use `IMPORTDATA()`

Comment: importdata is better option. Thanks

Comment: Any Idea on how to get the IMPORTDATA() function auto-refresh every 5 or 15 minutes using Google Script?

Comment: You might wanna just try changing recalculation in settings. If that doesn't work,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069891/google-sheets-importdata-importrange-speed-interval-ways-to-improve-it

Comment: Recalulation settings doesnt work for IMPORTDATA() function.